# Receive Port is not showing up in the list of Activation Subscriptions

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm troubleshooting a very generic BizTalk error that is resulting in transmission/routing failures (see below). Even though my receive location is started, it does not appear to be listening for anything.  When I run a query for all Activation Subscriptions, the receive port is not showing up in the list.  I cannot figure out why it is not subscribing to my send ports.

> Error:
>   The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification on receive locations. I'm new to BizTalk, as I have recently inherited the role of supporting it.  The problem ended up being an incorrect reference in an endpoint behavior extension in the receive location.

Comment: Voted down. The question you asked was precisely about Receive Ports subscriptions and  Dijkgraaf answered thoroughly. What does your self-selected answer add? I'm left wandering if what you did had any effect in subscriptions (and I would have learned something new) or if it was unrelated (and then it should not be the selected answer).

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I could have been much clearer. I posted the error I was receiving and described the action I took that resolved the error. There was a reference to an invalid WSDL operation name in the endpoint behavior extension configuration for the receive location.  This was preventing the send port from subscribing correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One Way Receive locations don't have Active subscriptions, only Orchestrations, Send Port Groups and Send Ports do. For a One Way your Send Port should be listening to your Receive Port rather than your Receive Port to your Send Port.

If it is a Request / Response port then see section below

**One Way Receive Location**

A Receive Location picks up from an external location and it goes via the associated receive port and publishes into the message box.

As your error clearly indicates that the message has been published to the message box the receive port is obviously working (although maybe not correctly) or it has been published back from a send port or orchestration.

What you have to check is

1. The context properties on the suspended message using BizTalk Administrator
2. The Subscription belonging to the Send Port / Orchestration that you expect to handle the message
3. Compare the two and see what does not match

The possibilities are

1. Your Receive Port is not promoting the properties you expect.  Check the receive pipeline and promoted properties on the schema.  If your pipeline is set to pass thru, only some of the standard promoted properties will be there and no message type or promoted properties from the schema, if you need those promoted properties set your pipeline to XMLReceive or a custom pipeline with either a XML Disassembler or a Flat File one.
2. Your Send Port / Orchestration are not in an Enlisted state, if they aren't enlisted then no subscriptions are published for them.  Enlist or Start them.
3. Your Send port/Orchestration subscription is wrong (does not match the message context properties), correct them so that they match.

**Request/Response Receive Port**

For a Request Response Receive location/port it creates an Instance Subscription for a message which looks for `BTS.EpmRRCorrelationToken` (which contains details of the hostinstance, port and a GUID) and `BTS.RouteDirectToTP == True`

It works out of the box if you either have a Request/Response Send port subscribing to a Request/Response receive port, or if you use a Request/Response Port in an Orchestration.   If you use separate Receive Send Ports in the Orchestration you need to set the above properties in your message construct shape manually.

See [Messaging-only request-response correlation](https://bveldhoen.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/messaging-only-request-response-correlation/)